# Flutter:Make model to save json into sqlite and return data as a object

Tags: sqlite, flutter

I have this json :

```
{
"ProductCoreId":0,
"LifeCycle":1,
"OwnerPartyRoleId":0,
"TriggerImages":null,
"TriggerImagesUrl":[
"/Files/Images/Channels/sdp.png"
],
"TriggerChannelIds":[
1287
],
"ActionImages":null,
"ActionImagesUrl":[]
}
```

As you can see i have 2 list `TriggerImagesUrl` and `TriggerChannelIds`. Now i want to save this model of json into sqlite so I made this class model according my json to save into database:

```
class ToolsByChannelIdDbModel {
  int productCoreId;
  int lifeCycle;
  int ownerPartyRoleId;
  Null triggerImages;
  String triggerImagesUrl;
  String triggerChannelIds;

      ToolsByChannelIdDbModel(
          {this.productCoreId,
          this.lifeCycle,
          this.ownerPartyRoleId,
          this.triggerImages,
          this.triggerImagesUrl,
          this.triggerChannelIds});

      ToolsByChannelIdDbModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        productCoreId = json['ProductCoreId'];
        lifeCycle = json['LifeCycle'];
        ownerPartyRoleId = json['OwnerPartyRoleId'];
        triggerImages = json['TriggerImages'];
        triggerImagesUrl = json['TriggerImagesUrl'];
        triggerChannelIds = json['TriggerChannelIds'];
      }

      Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
        final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
        data['ProductCoreId'] = this.productCoreId;
        data['LifeCycle'] = this.lifeCycle;
        data['OwnerPartyRoleId'] = this.ownerPartyRoleId;
        data['TriggerImages'] = this.triggerImages;
        data['TriggerImagesUrl'] = this.triggerImagesUrl;
        data['TriggerChannelIds'] = this.triggerChannelIds;
        return data;
      }
    }
```

As you now sqlite do not accept list as a type so i made a list as json string so i saved like this:

```
 ToolsByChannelIdDbModel model = ToolsByChannelIdDbModel();
 model.productCoreId = item.productCoreId;
 model.lifeCycle = item.lifeCycle;
 model.ownerPartyRoleId = item.ownerPartyRoleId;
 model.triggerImagesUrl = jsonEncode(item.triggerImagesUrl);
 model.triggerChannelIds = jsonEncode(item.triggerChannelIds);
 db.insert("tools_table", model.toJson());
```

`item.triggerImagesUrl` and `item.triggerChannelIds` are a list and i map these into json string to save into database.Till now everything is good and these list saved into database.
The problem is happening when i make a query and i want to decode the result of `db.rawQuery` into my object.

```
  Future<List<ToolsByChannelIdDbModel>> getTools(
      int channelId) async {
    List<ToolsByChannelIdDbModel> list = 
    try {
      var result = await DBProvider.db.getToolsById(channelId);
      result.forEach((item) {
        list.add(ToolsByChannelIdDbModel.fromJson(item));
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
    return list;
  }
}
```

`await DBProvider.db.getToolsById(channelId);` part works fine and returned a map of data and `triggerImagesUrl` and `triggerChannelIds` are json string, but when i want to convert map into my object by `ToolsByChannelIdDbModel.fromJson(item)` in this section :

> String triggerImagesUrl;   String triggerChannelIds;

In model i got error because i declare these fields as String but they are lists.

How can i store these lists into database and how can i map them into object?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
class ToolsByChannelIdDbModel {
    int productCoreId;
    int lifeCycle;
    int ownerPartyRoleId;
    dynamic triggerImages;
    List<String> triggerImagesUrl;
    List<int> triggerChannelIds;
    dynamic actionImages;
    List<dynamic> actionImagesUrl;

   /* Create instance without ID (database will auto generate one if you specified an 
   id column)*/       

   ToolsByChannelIdDbModel({
    this.lifeCycle,
    this.ownerPartyRoleId,
    this.triggerImages,
    this.triggerImagesUrl,
    this.triggerChannelIds,
    this.actionImages,
    this.actionImagesUrl,
  });

  // Create instance with ID  

  ToolsByChannelIdDbModel.withId({
    this.productCoreId,
    this.lifeCycle,
    this.ownerPartyRoleId,
    this.triggerImages,
    this.triggerImagesUrl,
    this.triggerChannelIds,
    this.actionImages,
    this.actionImagesUrl,
  });

  /* When you want to add object to database you can use .toMap() this will 
    convert ToolsByChannelIdDbModel instance to a Map*/  

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap()
  {
      var tempMap = Map<String, dynamic>();
      if(productCoreId != null)
      { 
          tempMap['productCoreId'] = productCoreId; 
      }
      tempMap['lifeCycle'] = lifeCycle;
      tempMap['ownerPartyRoleId'] = ownerPartyRoleId;
      tempMap['triggerImages'] = triggerImages;
      tempMap['triggerImagesUrl'] = List<dynamic>.from(triggerImagesUrl.map((x) => 
      x));
      tempMap['triggerChannelIds'] = List<dynamic>.from(triggerChannelIds.map((x) => 
      x));
      tempMap['actionImages'] = actionImages;
      tempMap['actionImagesUrl'] = List<dynamic>.from(actionImagesUrl.map((x) => 
      x));

      return tempMap;
  }

  /* Named constructor to create ToolsByChannelIdDbModel instance from a Map that you 
  get from database */     

  ToolsByChannelIdDbModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map)
  {
      this.productCoreId = map['productCoreId'];
      this.lifeCycle = map['lifeCycle'];
      this.ownerPartyRoleId = map['ownerPartyRoleId'];
      this.triggerImages = map['triggerImages'];
      this.triggerImagesUrl = List<String>.from(map['triggerImagesUrl'].map((x) => 
      x));
      this.triggerChannelIds = List<int>.from(map['triggerChannelIds'].map((x) => 
      x));
      this.actionImages = map['actionImages'];
      this.actionImagesUrl = List<dynamic>.from(map['actionImagesUrl'].map((x) => 
      x));
  }
}
```

Hope this helped!!

Comment: Thanks but you sure i can save a list into sqlite `tempMap['triggerImagesUrl'] = List<dynamic>.from(triggerImagesUrl.map((x) => 
      x));` @AbdelbakiBoukerche

Comment: As i mention above when you want to store a list inside sqlite you must convert the list as String.So when i run your code i got this error: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/hhJgwHmVgy/  because your code wants store a list `tempMap['triggerImagesUrl'] = List<dynamic>.from(triggerImagesUrl.map((x) => 
      x));` into database @abdelbakiboukerche

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/blob/master/sqflite/doc/supported_types.md)

Comment: That's mean if i change `"TriggerImagesUrl TEXT,"` in sql create table to  `"TriggerImagesUrl Uint8List,"` my problem is solved? and i can save list into database? @abdelbakiboukerche

Comment: It's documented that : Dart type List<int> is supported but not recommended (slow conversion). And you're trying to store List<String> so i don't think it will work, They alose mentioned that another solution is to encoded nested maps and lists as json (or other format).

Comment: Ok but what is your suggestion?I got some property as a list from web service and i want to save that inside database ! @abdelbakiboukerche

Comment: @sayreskabir, So i think you have 2 approaches, 1) Is to create new table to hold your list items and user FK with your main table. 2) convert List<String> to a String  store it in database, And when you want to use it split the String and create List from there.